# Decrypt a string with DES in PHP that's been encrypted by Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, phpseclib

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out exactly how to format everything to decrypt this string in PHP that's been encrypted in a custom Java class.

Here's the relevent functions from the Java class. The "salt" variable is a class variable byte array set earlier:

```
public DesEncrypter(String passPhrase) {
    try {
        // Create the key
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt,
                iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES")
                .generateSecret(keySpec);
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

        // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt,
                iterationCount);

        // Create the ciphers
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
    } catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    } catch (java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
    }
}

public String encrypt(String str) {
    try {
        // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

        // Encrypt
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

        // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
    } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public String decrypt(String str) {
    try {
        // Decode base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);

        // Decrypt
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

        // Decode using utf-8
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    } catch( Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here's what I have so far in PHP (FYI, I'm using this encryption library in PHP https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib):

```
$app->get('/decrypt', function () use ($app) {
    $data = '3aCRLRd3srA/QF4MQb0D+P==';
    $salt = pack('nvc*', 0xB7, 0x9A, 0xC1, 0x34, 0x26, 0x89, 0xW3, 0x30);
    $secret = "secret";
    $keyLength = 16;

    $cipher = new Crypt_DES(CRYPT_DES_MODE_CBC);
    $cipher->setPassword($secret, 'pbkdf2', 'md5', $salt, $keyLength);

    var_dump($cipher->decrypt($data));
});
```

Right now it's dumping out a bunch of binary, which I've tried base64_decoding, but that doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

If `key.getAlgorithm()` is "DES" then you need to provide a fully specified Cipher name like "DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding".

You will also need to provide the IV if it is non-null. Usually the IV is prepended to the ciphertext.

You can get the IV with `cipher.getIV()` and set with `$cipher->setIV('...');`.

Comment: When you say "fully specified Cipher name", that would be set in the 2nd parameter of the setPassword function, correct? I tried adding it there, and nothing changed. Also, I don't really have access to the java code in order to get the IV, just the source code. But from what I'm seeing, and who I've talked to, it doesn't look like one is set, so I think it's just NULL.

Comment: The problem is that `Cipher.getInstance("DES")` is not fully specified. You have no idea which block cipher mode and padding is actually used. Different JVMs/providers may have different defaults. If you can't change the java code, then you will need try different things in PHP. Maybe the Java code defaults to ECB mode in which case you will need to use `CRYPT_DES_MODE_ECB` in PHP.